# Must "work" be defined as something involving payment?

Tags: meaning

In different languages "work" means almost the same:

"activity involving mental or physical effort done in order to achieve a purpose or result"

However, there's no clear definition if it's must be paid or not.

I always thought "work" is something you must get paid for – otherwise it's not work.

Am I wrong? Could you please clarify this to me(with reliable sources of course, and not just an opinion – I value that too, tho).

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to English.SE! We appreciate your participation. If you have not already done so, please take [our tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour). Also, allow me to introduce you to our sister site, [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), which is especially useful for people learning English as a second language.

Comment: Thank you JBH, I appreciate it. BTW: Can I ask you if you found any mistakes in my post? :)

Comment: Anyone propagating an idea that work was not work unless it involved payment, would quickly be in monumental trouble with all sorts of categories of people, not least from my wife.

Comment: Yeah, especially "yard work" and "house work".  (Not!!)

Comment: Consider the statement, "I have more work to do on this story before I'll let you read it." If I'm not planning on selling it to a publisher - for example, I'm writing it as a gift to someone - I'm not going to be getting paid for it, but I'm still doing work on it.

Comment: Yes, but only a few.  This site was originally created "for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts."  That's what the tour explains.  We frequently have visitors who don't realize that another site exists specifically to help people learning English as a second language, which is why I introduce it to new visitors.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Consider when you'd say "He's quite a piece of work!"  No one actually got paid to produce the idiot.

Answer (score 1):

Work is not something that you need to be paid for, there are plenty of examples of non-paid work - housework, homework, voluntary work, community work, [charity work](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/charity-work)

Work is simply expending effort on some kind of task. It is not necessarily done for monetary gain.